# Waiting on multiple asynchronous POST requests

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient

I need to make multiple asynchronous calls from inside a wcf service hosted in IIS (might be relevant, I don't know). The calls are to other services, but I make them by POSTing a string to the service URL. Calling them synchronously works, but I have more than a dozen calls, and they're completely independent, so I would like to speed them up by calling them asynchronously.

Now, I realize that I could simply use multiple threads for this - and it might be the easiest solution - but I thought I'd give async a try.

My code is similar to this:

```
public delegate void Callback(string response);

public static void InvokeAsync(string request, string url, Callback callback)
  where TResponse: class
{
  var web = new WebClient();
  web.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  web.UploadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => callback.Invoke(e.Result);
  web.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url), request);
}

//...
var lockObj = new object();
foreach (var item in list)
  InvokeAsync(item, url, response => { lock(lockObj) newList.Add(response); });
```

The above should work, I believe; however, my problem is that I have no idea how to wait until all the responses are back. If I use a counter and wait in a loop until it becomes zero, there won't be any CPU left to handle the callbacks. Same with using some form of semaphore, I believe. Is there a non-blocking way to wait until I got back all the responses? (Changing the method signature to also take a callback will only move the problem one level up, I'm afraid.)

[Edit] Here's a very close question - [How to invoke async operation as sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165436/how-to-invoke-async-operation-as-sync) - but I need to wait on *multiple* async operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You use an `AutoResetEvent` for this.**

Try the following for your last two lines:

```
var waitEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

foreach (var item in list)
  InvokeAsync(item, url, response => { lock(lockObj) newList.Add(response); waitEvent.Set(); });

while (newList.Count < list.Count)
  waitEvent.WaitOne();
```

All items should be completed when `newList` contains as many items as `list`. When a new item comes in, you add it to `newList`. Then, you signal the `waitEvent` that "something" happened to `newList`.

In the main thread, you simply wait until you have enough items in `newList` and you wait for this by waiting on changes to `newList`, which `waitEvent` informs you of.

Answer (score 0):

According to HTTP protocol, a client can only open 2 connections to a service.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/02/08/why-only-two-concurrent-requests-for-load-testing.aspx agrees with you, but indicates a way to fix that; I plan on using the suggested solution if I hit that limitation.

Comment: The HTTP protocol has no overall limit on connections, but does have 2 connections (or 2 times the number of clients for proxy or gateway code) as a SHOULD for good reason; it does tend that in many cases, 2 per server is the most efficient number to have open at a time. .NET enforces this, but it is configurable.